# Pull requests and work item linking in Visual Studio 2015 with non-TFS remote Git repo

Tags: git, visual-studio, team-foundation-server, pull-requests

We use TFS and Visual Studio 2015 at work but don't get full benefit from the ALM features as we have code in non-TFS Git repos.

We would like to integrate these products in with all the TFS goodies like checkin-to-work item linking, in-IDE pull requests, etc.

Is there any way to access these features in a non-TFS-hosted Git repo?

Answer (score 1):

You can pull in those branches into you git-tfs hybrid repository, then use `git tfs checkintool`. This should open up a window that looks similar to the Visual Studio interface, and should allow you to link work items.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

While some features work, like build, you will not get any of the Pull Request, or Branch by Work Item, or even work item links without using a Git repo in TFS. I recommend that you push your code to TFS and have everything integrated.